# display recursive model data in views cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Let's say that I have a recursive (meaning it has field parent_id, lft and rght) model called in a cakephp application. I want to display this recursive data on a page. I get my data with a find like this:

```
$recursive_data_results = $this->Model->find('threaded');
```

This find will give me my data with all the children of each node. Is it possible to display this data on a page without having to loop through every single node and their children node and so on...? I don't want to loop through each node because let's say I have like 15 of them or something, I don't wanna do 15 foreach loops.

Comment: Not getting clearly.. YOu want to reduce the data mean use recursive levels

Answer (score 1):

If you want nested lists in your view try
[Nested lists](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3anestedList)

Otherwise [Create helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/helpers.html#creating-helpers) to handle your data.